# CRAN check rgdal not available for checking

Tags: r, cran, rgdal

I have an R package that I successfully submitted to CRAN over a year ago. I am ready to submit an update, however I see in the [package check results](https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_envirem.html) an error: `Package suggested but not available for checking: ‘rgdal’`

This R package passes checks with `R CMD check --as-cran` on macOS, winbuilder with R-devel and on ubuntu. But I don't understand why rgdal was not available for checking in that one instance, and I am trying to avoid this same error cropping up again.

A quick google search shows this same error showing up for quite a few R packages, always only for r-release-osx-x86_64.

Is this something I should be concerned with?

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I was able to ignore this issue, and this was not a problem. The same error did not crop up with the submission of the package update.